# Embedding Python: undefined reference to `_imp__Py_Initialize'

Tags: c++, python-3.x, python-embedding

I am trying to embed python 3.7.0 in a C++ application and use MinGW to compile.

```
#include "Dependencies/include/Python.h"


int main()
{

    PyObject* myPointer;
    Py_Initialize();
    return 0;
}
```

I compile with this:

> g++ ./TestEmbedding.cpp

I get this error:

> undefined reference to `_imp__Py_Initialize'

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:
Found and Answer:

The path to the python libs file needs to be included. I personally am now using Visual Studio and just included it in the settings but I think MinGW can do it with some command line adjustments.

include something similar to this in library paths.
C:Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib

Comment: There is no python folder in my local folder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build with Python headers:

```
g++ TestEmbedding.cpp `python3-config --includes` -o TestEmbedding
```